# jQuery error - Cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I updated to the latest version of jQuery and I see this error.

**Error:**

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method '`div.panes > div`'

**Complete Snippet:**

**html:**

```
<div id="nav"> <!-- Start Page Navigation -->
    <ul class="tabs page">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div> <!-- End Page Navigation -->
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.header div.version").css({ '-moz-border-radius': '6px', '-webkit-border-radius': '6px' });
    $("div#contact_form .text_input").css({ '-moz-border-radius': '4px', '-webkit-border-radius': '4px' });
    $("div#about div.right").css({ '-moz-border-radius' : '8px', '-webkit-border-radius': '8px' });
    $("div#contact_form p label").css({ 
            '-moz-border-radius-topleft': '4px', 
            '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft': '4px', 
            '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius' : '4px',
            '-webkit-border-top-left-radius' : '4px'  
    });
    $("select").css({ '-khtml-appearance' : 'none' });
    $('#reviews').serialScroll({
      items: 'div',
      axis: 'y',
      duration: 800,
      interval: 5000,
      cycle: true
    });
    $('#reviews').trigger('next');
    $("a.screenshots").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'       :   400, 
            'speedOut'      :   400, 
            'overlayShow'   :   false
        });
        $('input#send').click(function() {
        var name = $('input#name').val();
        var email = $('input#email').val();
                var topic = $('select#topic option:selected').val();
        var message = $('textarea#message').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'scripts/send_email.php',
            data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&topic=' + topic + '&message=' + message,

            success: function(results) {
                $('p.validation').html(results);
            }
        }); // end ajax
    });
 $("#ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", { history: true });
});
```

I don't see the error if I use:

```
 $("#content ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", { history: true });
```

[image]

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Did you also update to the latest version of jQuery UI?

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.8.2 version of jQuery and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Do you have another instance of `ul.tabs` on your page? It would really help to share a snippet of html that recreates this error, or a page we can view to see the problem.

Comment: `#content ul.tabs` is not the same as `#ul.tabs`.  `#ul` implies you have a node whose id is `id='ul'`.

Comment: Your selector should be `$('ul.tabs')` not `$('#ul.tabs')`

Comment: $('ul.tabs') didn't work either. I think that the div is not loaded when the $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", { history: true }); is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following fixed my problem:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs($("div.panes > div"), { history: true });
```

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
  $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", { history: true });
```

instead of this

```
 $("#ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", { history: true });
```